# Complexified bundle $\xi \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to its conjugate $\overline{\xi \otimes \mathbb{C}}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-numbers, vector-bundles

The following appears in Milnor's *Characteristic classes*, Chapter 15, and I don't fully understand what's going on.

Let $\xi$ be a real vector bundle. Milnor claims that the complexification $\xi \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to its conjugate bundle $\overline{\xi \otimes \mathbb{C}}$. Milnor introduces the (fiberwise) map
\begin{align*}
f: \xi \otimes \mathbb{C} & \to \overline{\xi \otimes \mathbb{C}} \\
x+iy & \mapsto x-iy,
\end{align*}
which certainly is an isomorphism of *real* bundles. He also notices the identity
$$f(i(x + iy)) = -y -ix = -i f(x+iy),$$
but I think this exactly shows that $f$ is *not* an isomorphism of complex bundles, because it is not $\mathbb{C}$-linear, but conjugate-linear. And that is not even that special, because any complex bundle is conjugate linear to its conjugate bundle, via the identity map.

However on the next page he uses that isomorphism to conclude that $\xi \otimes \mathbb{C}$ and  $\overline{\xi \otimes \mathbb{C}}$ have the same Chern classes.

What am I missing here?

Comment: the conjugate bundle is the original bundle but with a new multiplication by $i$, defined as the original multiplication by $-i$. So it is an iso.

Comment: @user8268 Oh right, what a confusing thing :D  If you make this into an answer, I would be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notation's sake let $\kappa\colon \xi \otimes\mathbb{C} \to \xi \otimes \mathbb{C}$ and $\overline{\kappa}\colon \overline{\xi \otimes\mathbb{C}} \to \overline{\xi \otimes \mathbb{C}}$ be the names of the complex structures. Explicitly, for $z$ in some fibre $F\otimes \mathbb{C}$ we have $\kappa(z) = i\cdot z$ and $\overline{\kappa} = -i \cdot (z)$. Then for $f\colon \xi \otimes\mathbb{C} \to \overline{\xi \otimes\mathbb{C}}$ to be an isomorphism of *vector bundles with complex structure* it means $f(\kappa(v)) = \overline{\kappa}(f(v))$ for any $v$ in any fibre $F_x \otimes \mathbb{C}$. But if you unravel the definitions of $\kappa$ and $\overline{\kappa}$ this is precisely what the identity you wrote down is saying.